# Laravel Eloquent order by using relation data

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by

I have the following 2 tables:

```
Cars
----
id | created_at

and

Repaired
id | cars_id | updated_at
```

I want to display all cars, ordered by `created_at` desc, BUT also ordered by `updated_at` from the `Repaired` pivot table. Repaired can have many entries of specific `cars_id`.

So if `carA` is created_at `2017-02-20`, and `carB` is created_at `2016-01-10`, but the `updated_at` in Repaired for `carB` is on `2017-02-22`, i want to display `carB` BEFORE `carA`, because the relation is "newer".

I also don't want do load the data from the relation table.

I tried the follwing:

```
$cars = $model->load(['repaired' => function($query) {
    return $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
}])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
```

and

```
$model->join('repaired', 'repaired.cars_id', '=', 'cars.id')
      ->orderBy('repaired.updated_at', 'desc')
      ->orderBy('cars.created_at', 'desc')
      ->select('cars.*');
```

^ this query return all items from the Repaired table, even if the `updated_at` field is `NULL`. And i can't group them.

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `touch parent timestamps` feature in Eloquent, to update the `updated_at` for the car, every time Repaired is updated.

In your Repaired model just add this line:

```
protected $touches = ['car'];
```

This is assuming your relation method is named `car()` of course.

Then you can do this:

```
Cars::orderBy('updated_at');
```

Every time a row in the `Repaired` table is added or updated, the car specified in the `car` relation will have its `updated_at` set to the same time. That way you can order by it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $popular_posts = Post::withCount('favorite_to_users')
            ->orderBy('view_count', 'desc')
            ->orderBy('favorite_to_users_count', 'desc')
            ->take(5)->get();
```